# PHP in bootstrap contact form does not work correctly, someone can figure out what I did wrong?

Tags: php, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, email

I've made a contact form for my website, included the html and the php, it does send an email which does show "name: email: message:" but after that it's empty, so it doesn't show what you type in the form, please help!

Here is the html:

```
<form action="thankyou.php" method="post">
<div class="col-md-5" style="margin-top:15px;">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="contact-name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Naam</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact-name" placeholder="First & Last name" />
            </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
        <label for="contact-email" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="margin-top:15px;">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10" style="margin-top:15px;">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact-name" placeholder="example@domain.com" />
            </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
        <label for="contact-message" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="margin-top:15px;">Message</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10" style="margin-top:15px;">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="4"></textarea>
            </div>
            </div>
            
            <button style="btn-align:center; margin-left:88px; margin-top:15px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Verstuur</button>
 
</div>
</div>
    </div>
 </form>
```

Here is the php:

```
<?
$name = $_POST['contact-name'];
$email = $_POST['contact-email'];
$message = $_POST['contact-message'];

$email_message = "
Name:".$name."
Email:".$email."
Message:".$message." 


";

mail ( "email@example.com" , "New inquiry", $email_message);
?>
```

Comment: using this http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and set to display the potential errors, would have helped here. Make sure that short open tags are also enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form fields are all missing the name attribute. Without it that data is *not* sent.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="contact-name" id="contact-name" placeholder="First & Last name" />
                                        ^^^^
                                    This is missing for all form fields
```